# Google map and key changed online

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I looking for expert of php who wants to help me in this strange problem.
This script added bellow sometimes works good.
I have three domains pointed to one directory. Google maps requires api key unique for each domain.
My script have to change the key value online.
I see that page from IE8 always are showed correctly but from Chrom and Firefox this script has problem but not always. Ofcourse I controled source of page and there was empty where should be script src.
Thank you
Have a nice day!

There is full code added in HEAD of page.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='napuzaka.pl') 
    {echo "<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAYTZHyOQ5V62SeMKaQnfsmBTpouANZ5f-taQv7LHvODzA4dkDHBSIDoDMuDCbfgg0tAyoHhFajBNCJQ' type='text/javascript'></script>"; }
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='xn--napuaka-zwb.pl') 
    {echo "<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAYTZHyOQ5V62SeMKaQnfsmBSz8IVGRhEo79udyNR7B2dzTza61xRpT9lPIg18vhQmddrMIlSVereK3g' type='text/javascript'></script>";}
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='xn--przychodnia-na-puaka-yle.pl') 
    {echo "<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAYTZHyOQ5V62SeMKaQnfsmBTIBRlPbe0ldXIT_VQB31noUDT8mRReXxc12wAWIs4fuEXiTbsZ0HvViA' type='text/javascript'></script>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in the situations that it doesn't work and add them to the if... It is related on how browsers parse IDN (Internationalized domain name) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: Thank you, I changed from echo to print but this problem is still when I browse this page from Chrome

Comment: that's not what I said. do echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in that situations and see the value. I'm sure that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead use a variable to control the domain and then `echo` that line with a switch statement?

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

switch ($page)
{

case 'http://xn--przychodnia-na-puaka-yle.pl': 
print '<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;hl=en&amp;sensor=false&amp;key="ABQIAAAAYTZHyOQ5V62SeMKaQnfsmBTIBRlPbe0ldXIT_VQB31noUDT8mRReXxc12wAWIs4fuEXiTbsZ0HvViA" type="text/javascript"></script>';

break;

case 'http://napuzaka.pl': /* same with this case just different API Key*/ 
break;

case 'http://xn--napuaka-zwb.pl': /* same with this case just different API Key*/ 
break;

}
```

Also, using `print` instead of `echo` saves some memory during the process, as the `echo` function has its own micro-factory and should be used only if you are printing variables or text with variables in it for sake of making it faster.